# Force SSH to prompt for user

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, terminal, openssh

Since I am very used to being prompted for my user-id while using putty or MobaXterm in SSH sessions I expected to have the same behaviour when using SSH in the windows terminal but that is not the case.

If I try it without specifying a user via

```
ssh <servername>
```

the command line will just use my windows user which I don't want to, since all of my hosts have too many technical users and entering them on the fly is way simpler for me than creating 3-4 a configs/profiles for each host.

I already tried creating a config file "C:\Users<my-user>.ssh\config" and played around with overwriting the "User" config via making a blank entry like

```
Host *
    User
```

which obviously didn't work.

Do you think I need to write some sort of wrapper in order to get a proper "login as:" prompt or am I just missing some simple configuration that needs to be adapted?

Comment: `entering them on the fly is way simpler for me than creating 3-4 a configs/profiles for each host.` Can't you just use `user@server`?

Comment: Yes I can but since I have a lot of hosts I'd like to have just one entry for every host in my profile to keep the list tidy and overseeable

Comment: Adjust your config to a specific host and specify the user in this section. Please see the [OpenSSH Arch Wiki Entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/OpenSSH#Client_usage), as this may provide a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I found a solution for this.

When creating a new profile I added the following line as a command:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe /c "$login_user = Read-Host -Prompt 'login as'; ssh $login_user@<hostname>"
```

Replace the "<hostname>" above with whatever server you want to access.